# Sort wordpress posts by the amount of shared tags with current post

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is where my code is at so far. It pulls in all posts that share tags with the current post, but I can't figure out how to sort them in a descending fashion where the first posts shares the most tags with the current post. Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID, 'Asset' );
if ( $tags ) {
    $tag_ids = array();
    foreach( $tags as $individual_tax ) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tax->term_id;
    $args = array(
        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
        'post_type' => 'Asset',
        'post__not_in'          => array( $post->ID ),
        'posts_per_page'        => 3,
    );

    $my_query = new wp_query( $args );

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ){
            $my_query->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'asset' );

        }
    }

    wp_reset_query();

}
```

Updated Code:

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID, 'Asset' );
if ( $tags )  {
$tag_ids = array();
foreach( $tags as $individual_tax ) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tax->term_id;
$args = array(
    'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
    'post_type' => 'Asset',
    'post__not_in'          => array( $post->ID ),
    'posts_per_page'        => 3,
);

function order_results($post1, $post2) {

    $tags1 = wp_get_post_tags($post1);
    $tags2 = wp_get_post_tags($post1);

    $tag_cnt1 = 0;
    $tag_cnt2 = 0;
    foreach ($tags1 as $tag) {
        if (in_array($tag->term_id, $tag_ids)) {

        }
    }
    foreach ($tags2 as $tag) {
        if (in_array($tag->term_id, $tag_ids)) {
            ++$tag_cnt2;
        }
    }

    return ($tag_cnt1 < $tag_cnt2) ? -1 : 1;

}

$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
$posts = $my_query->posts;

// Sort
usort( $posts, 'order_results');

// Print
foreach ($posts as $post) {                     

    get_template_part( 'asset' );

}

wp_reset_query();

}
```

Final Working Code:

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID, 'Asset' );
if ( $tags )  {
$tag_ids = array();
foreach( $tags as $individual_tax ) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tax->term_id;
$args = array(
    'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
    'post_type' => 'Asset',
    'post__not_in'          => array( $post->ID ),
    'posts_per_page'        => 3,
);

// Sort
function order_results($post1, $post2) {
    //Get current post tags
    global $tag_ids;

    // Reduce down to tags ids
    $tags1 = wp_get_post_tags($post1->ID);
    $tags2 = wp_get_post_tags($post2->ID);
    $tags_num_1 = array();
    $tags_num_2 = array();

    foreach( $tags1 as $tags ) $tags_num_1[] = $tags->term_id;
    foreach( $tags2 as $tags ) $tags_num_2[] = $tags->term_id;

    // Set tag count
    $tag_cnt1 = 0;
    $tag_cnt2 = 0;

    // Count tags
    foreach ($tags_num_1 as $tag) {
        if (in_array($tag, $tag_ids)) {
            $tag_cnt1++;
        }
    }
    foreach ($tags_num_2 as $tag) {
        if (in_array($tag, $tag_ids)) {
            $tag_cnt2++;
        }
    }

    // Order
    return ($tag_cnt1 < $tag_cnt2) ? 1 : -1;

}

$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
$posts = $my_query->posts;

usort( $posts, 'order_results');


// Print
foreach ($posts as $post) {                     
    setup_postdata( $post );

    get_template_part( 'asset' );

}

wp_reset_query();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP_Query does not allow you to specify an arbitrary sort criteria. You would need to sort the results afterwards, e.g.

```
function order_results($post1, $post2) {
    $tags1 = wp_get_post_tags($post1->ID);
    $tags2 = wp_get_post_tags($post2->ID);
    $tag_cnt1 = 0;
    $tag_cnt2 = 0;
    foreach ($tags1 as $tag) {
        if (in_array($tag->term_id, $tag_ids)) {

        }
    }
    foreach ($tags2 as $tag) {
        if (in_array($tag->term_id, $tag_ids)) {
            ++$tag_cnt2;
        }
    }
    return ($tag_cnt1 < $tag_cnt2) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort( $my_query->posts, 'order_results');
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I understand whats happening here, but I am not sure how to translate it to actually effecting the output. Any help?

Comment: The WP have_posts() and the_post() are just wrappers for common PHP. I'd just extract the posts like $posts = $my_query->posts, sort them, and then use a normal PHP loop like foreach ($posts as $post) instead of the WP loop.

Comment: Right after the foreach, add "setup_postdata( $post );". That sets up things like the_title() etc. When you say it doesn't work, what actually happens?

Comment: It returns the posts, but they are not sorted by common tags. They are sorted in a descending order by id.

Comment: Oops. Just noticed a typo in my answer. Change  parameters to wp_get_post_tags to ID. See revised answer.

Comment: Yes! Made a couple more changes and everything is working great! I updated my post with the final code. Thanks!